# swagger-codegen simple models missing

Tags: java, swagger-codegen

I'm realizing my second API with swagger/swagger-codegen.
After having a really good start with my first one I'm somewhat stuck with the following problem:
I'm having multiple definitions like the following:

```
TopIssueReference:
  description: Id of a top issue
  type: string
  example:
    itemid: 'd32c1213-4773-442e-9c5f-f5d516358869'
```

All those definitions only are aliases for type string, some with format date-time, some naked like the one above.

The swagger editor is fine with those definitions.

When I use one of them in a `$ref` clause within some object definition the generator produces a reference to a class named like my definition, `TopIssueReference` in this case.

The generated `TopIssueReference` class is the following (in java):

```
@ApiModel(description = "Id of a top issue")
public class TopIssueReference  {
  @Override
  public String toString()  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class TopIssueReference {");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

which is not really useful.

Does anybody have an idea what's going wrong here?
Shouldn't the generator either produce a reference to a String or at least make `TopIssueReference` derive from a string (however useful that may be)?

For some of those definitions, the generator does not generate any class at all - but the references are still there, so the resulting code does not even compile.

I tried generating servers and clients with java and python, and both are having the same problem.

Comment: Looks like a known issue: [#2314](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/2314), [#3483](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/3483)

Comment: Thanks, didn't actually find this one myself, but it accurately describes my problem.

Comment: Can you try the latest master? SNAPSHOT can be found in the README. I remember there's a PR addressing this but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try Bellow code to your swagger file to generate code.

```
TopIssueReference:
    description: Id of a top issue
    type: object
    properties:
      itemid:
        type: string
```

i hope it's useful to you ...!